# What does "enrollment" mean here?

Tags: translation

I have a sentence to translate:

> The school shall notify parents in writing at the beginning of each
>   school year, and upon any enrollment during the school year, of the
>   obligation to ensure all children of compulsory attendance age attend school.

wiki gives such definition of enrollment: "the process of initiating attendance to a school", which seems like a one time process that doesn't happen during the school year to me.

So what does it mean here?

Comment: Some people cannot start school at the beginning of the year, so they enroll during

Comment: You could also enroll to a new course at school, maybe even during the year.

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing what the context is. What is it the school must inform the parents of? What is the document?

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet, added the rest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why yes, it is a one-time process, but sometimes kids have to join school in the middle of the year (for example, if they move from one city to another). So upon the enrollment or at the beginning of the school year (meaning the kid is already enrolled), parents are informed about their obligation to control their child's attendance.

Comment: oh so in other words all parents get notified once, some at the beginning of the year, and some during it?

Comment: Yeah, parents, whose kids are already at school, are notified at the beginning of the school year. But if a kid enrolls in the middle of the year, school still needs to inform his parents about their obligations, so they do it.